# Extra Scrolling and Space in web view in android

Tags: android, webview

I am using the WebView in which I am opening the website but its scrolling more. It scrolling less in browser but in webview it's scrolling more. How can i fit same as Browser in the Web View.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.testwebview);
        final ProgressBar myPB = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.testprogressbar);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        // Add WebViewClient to be notified of page load
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                // Show webview and hide progress bar
                myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myPB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://pmtestonline.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847798/how-to-use-webview-as-a-browser-in-android-application ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is that you should look these two questions

[WebView doesn't resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311321/webview-doesnt-resize)

but from that I see you need to create new WebView every time

[WebView height = wrap_content with changing font size doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765059/webview-height-wrap-content-with-changing-font-size-doesnt-work)

And the answers too...

EDIT for creating new webview programmatically

[Webview in programmatically created RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221777/webview-in-programmatically-created-relativelayout)

and this also [Im trying to programmatically insert a WebView into my Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815027/im-trying-to-programmatically-insert-a-webview-into-my-code)